# iPhone, Mobile Safari, YouTube ... stay on page

Tags: youtube, iphone, mobile-safari

Is it possible to have a YouTube video played on a web page in Safari on the iPhone, and have the 'done' button and 'video finished' event send the user back to the mobile web page they came from?

Currently, it seems like i'm only able to direct them to YouTube.app to view the video ... but they then remain in YouTube.app and are presented with the videos comments and other such information, and I do not wish to display this information.

If this is possible, please provide a link to a site with documentation/examples or an example in your response.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use YouTube's new IFRAME-based embed code (I believe they give it to you by default now when you click their embed button...?) and on an iPhone, it will be rendered as an HTML5 video if possible.

When users tap the play icon on it, it will launch the standard video viewer, not the YouTube app. When they exit the video, they'll be back on your webpage.

The new embed code looks like this:

```
<iframe
    title="YouTube video player"
    width="480"
    height="390"
    src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO-ID"
    frameborder="0"
    allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

This is more or less what they do in the new [YouTube webapp](http://m.youtube.com/#/home), except that they don't need the IFRAME (they just do the HTML5 embed on their own page).

Comment: although the question was originally asked before YouTube had the new HTML5 Video implementation, I'm accepting this answer because it is correct.